# Read .csv files and convert the rows into dict for looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This script tries to parse `.csv` files and returns an iterable object to fetch one row at a time to do some process. It works fine but I think it needs improvements to make it efficient.

````
    import os
    from csv import DictReader


    class CSVHandler:
        DELIMIT = ','  # delimiter for csv
        FIELDS = set(list(['foo', 'bar']))  # fields that I want

        def __init__(self, file_path: str):
            self.file_path = file_path
            self.file_obj = None
            self.reader = DictReader([])

        def read_file(self):
            if self._is_file_ok:
                try:
                    self.file_obj = open(self.file_path, newline='')
                    self.reader = DictReader(self.file_obj)
                    unmatched = self._is_fields_ok
                    if isinstance(unmatched, set):
                        print(f"Warning : field set's unmatched! {unmatched}")
                except IOError:
                    print(f'Unable to open/read file : "{self.file_path}"')
            else:
                print(f'Invalid file : "{self.file_path}"')
            return self

        @property
        def _is_file_ok(self):
            if os.path.isfile(self.file_path):
                if os.path.exists(self.file_path):
                    if self.file_path.endswith('.csv'):
                        return True
            return False

        @property
        def _is_fields_ok(self):
            if self.reader or not self.FIELDS:
                return self.FIELDS - set(self.reader.fieldnames)
            return False

        def _trim_row(self, row: dict):
            trimmed_row = dict.fromkeys(self.FIELDS, None)
            for field in self.FIELDS:
                if field in row:
                     trimmed_row[field] = row[field]
            return trimmed_row

        def __enter__(self):
            return self

        def __iter__(self):
            return (self._trim_row(dict(row)) for row in self.reader)

        def __next__(self):
            return self._trim_row(dict(next(self.reader)))

        def __len__(self):
            return len(list(self.reader))

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            if self.file_obj is not None:
                self.file_obj.close()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with CSVHandler('file_name.csv').read_file() as csv_h:
            for rows in csv_h:
                pass
```
````

Comment: Is using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) an option?

Comment: Please consider adding your real code and telling us more about what it's doing and why you wrote it.

Comment: Could you also remove the request for help in your title. Asking for code imporvment is implied in all questions.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CR!

As others recommended, you need to be more clear. I can give you some stylistic critique.

I like that you are using type hinting in the parameters. I recommend you also hint the return types for your functions like:

```
def _trim_row(self, row: dict) -> list:
            trimmed_row = dict.fromkeys(self.FIELDS, None)
            for field in self.FIELDS:
                if field in row:
                     trimmed_row[field] = row[field]
            return trimmed_row
```

Now, more importantly I recommend you [create strong documentation](https://realpython.com/documenting-python-code/) for your code so that we can understand the idea behind it, what bugs it has, as well as its efficiency failures (you can use [codetags](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0350/) such as `# BUG:` or `# FIXME:`).

For your convenience, you can also edit your code in an [IDE that enables pylinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint), where you can get suggestions about how stylistically good your code is, I recommend VS Code with the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and [autoDocstring](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring) extensions.

By putting your code in VS Code, I got the following suggestions for improvements:

```
""" [INSERT MODULE DESCRIPTION] """

import os
from csv import DictReader


class CSVHandler:
    """[INSERT CLASS DESCRIPTION]
    """
    DELIMIT = ','  # delimiter for csv
    FIELDS = set(list(['foo', 'bar']))  # fields that I want

    def __init__(self, file_path: str):
        """[summary]

        Arguments:
            file_path {str} -- [description]
        """
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.file_obj = None
        self.reader = DictReader([])

    def read_file(self):
        """[summary]

        Returns:
            [type] -- [description]
        """
        if self._is_file_ok:
            try:
                self.file_obj = open(self.file_path, newline='')
                self.reader = DictReader(self.file_obj)
                unmatched = self._is_fields_ok
                if isinstance(unmatched, set):
                    print(f"Warning : field set's unmatched! {unmatched}")
            except IOError:
                print(f'Unable to open/read file : "{self.file_path}"')
        else:
            print(f'Invalid file : "{self.file_path}"')
        return self

    @property
    def _is_file_ok(self):
        """[summary]

        Returns:
            [type] -- [description]
        """
        if os.path.isfile(self.file_path):
            if os.path.exists(self.file_path):
                if self.file_path.endswith('.csv'):
                    return True
        return False

    @property
    def _is_fields_ok(self):
        """[summary]

        Returns:
            [type] -- [description]
        """
        if self.reader or not self.FIELDS:
            return self.FIELDS - set(self.reader.fieldnames)
        return False

    def _trim_row(self, row: dict):
        """[summary]

        Arguments:
            row {dict} -- [description]

        Returns:
            [type] -- [description]
        """
        trimmed_row = dict.fromkeys(self.FIELDS, None)
        for field in self.FIELDS:
            if field in row:
                trimmed_row[field] = row[field]
        return trimmed_row

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self._trim_row(dict(row)) for row in self.reader)

    def __next__(self):
        return self._trim_row(dict(next(self.reader)))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(list(self.reader))

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.file_obj is not None:
            self.file_obj.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with CSVHandler('file_name.csv').read_file() as csv_h:
        for rows in csv_h:
            pass
```

Another suggestion that I can give you is to know what you are importing and import just what you need. So, `import os` should be replaced with `from os import path` and remove `os.` from `if os.path.isfile(self.file_path):` and `if os.path.exists(self.file_path):`.

Following this, you will understand your code better, and you will be able to ask more specific questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

In a fully-fledged class, `DELIMIT` and `FIELDS` could have been defined as **parameters** rather than left hardcoded like this:

```
DELIMIT = ','  # delimiter for csv
FIELDS = set(list(['foo', 'bar']))  # fields that I want
```

Regarding **exception handling**, I recommend that you keep the full details including the stack trace - you don't have to display it to the user but it's good to have a **log** somewhere to investigate errors. Debugging can be difficult if you have to rely only on what your program outputs. For example, if an `except IOError` is raised it will not be immediately apparent what happened: was it a permission issue or the file does not exist or something else ?

Using the `logger` module you can output messages to *multiple destinations* at the same time, for example show a simplified message on the console but log more details to a file, also the [logging levels](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#levels) can be different for each destination.

In this function `os.path.exists` is redundant, `isfile` will suffice:

```
def _is_file_ok(self):
    if os.path.isfile(self.file_path):
        if os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            if self.file_path.endswith('.csv'):
                return True
    return False
```

From the [doc:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

> *os.path.isfile(path)*
>
> Return True if path is an **existing** regular file. This follows symbolic
>   links, so both islink() and isfile() can be true for the same path.

`isfile` and `endswith` are boolean functions, so you can directly return the result of the function. In a slightly more concise way:

```
def _is_file_ok(self):
    if os.path.isfile(self.file_path):
        return self.file_path.endswith('.csv')
    else:
        return False
```

On a final note, I also agree that Pandas would do the job fine with much less code.

Comment: great suggestions, thank you

Comment: I meant to ask if this approach is right to read .csv file and return an iterable. If an error occurs in any part of the script it should log and return an empty iterable